# Disable SwiftUI frame animation on appear

Tags: animation, swiftui, swiftui-animation, onappear, swiftui-transition

#### The Goal

Let's say I have a `List` or a `LazyVGrid` that displays multiple items nested inside a `ScrollView`. I use a `ForEach` view to generate the individual item views:

```
ForEach(items) { item in
    ItemView(item)
}
```

The `items` array might be a `@State` property on the view itself or a `@Published` property on a view model that conforms to `@ObservableObject` (I'll go with the first in this example).

Now when I change the `items` array by inserting or removing elements, I want the changes to be animated in a particular fashion, so I add a `transition` and an `animation` modifier as follows:

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVGrid(columns: 2) {
        ForEach(items) { item in
            ItemView(item)
                .transition(.scale)
        }
    }
}
.animation(.default, value: items)
```

This works beautifully.

#### The Problem

The only hiccup is that this code also causes the entire `ScrollView` to scale from zero to its full size when the view first appears. (It makes sense as the items array is empty initially before the items are fetched from the store, so the array does change in deed.)

#### Solution Attempt

To solve the problem, I obviously need to make the animation dependent on a property that does **not** change before the view has appeared and the items array is loaded. So I created such a property as a plain Boolean and toggle it whenever the `items` array changes, but only after `didAppear` has been called:

```
@State var changedState: Bool = false
@State var didAppear: Bool = false

@State var items: [Item] = [] {
    didSet {
        if didAppear {
            changedState.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Then I change the `value` of the animation modifier to this new property:

```
.animation(.default, value: changedState)
```

✅ That solves the problem. However, it feels very "ugly" and like a lot of overhead.

#### The Question

Is there any other (more elegant/concise) way to disable the initial scale animation?

---

#### ‍ Edit: Minimal Code Example

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var items: [Int] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(), GridItem()]) {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(height: 50)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .transition(.scale)
                    }
                }
            }
            .animation(.default, value: items)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        let newItem = items.last.map { $0 + 1 } ?? 0
                        items.append(newItem)
                    } label: {
                        Text("Add Item")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            items = [Int](0...10)
        }
    }
}
```

This is how the initial animation looks like:

[image: Step 1] →
[image: Step 2] →
[image: Step 3]

Comment: I'm not seeing this initial scaling animation when I build a very simple example, but I do have an idea on how to prevent it. Can you share a full view that does this so I can confirm?

Comment: I can't share the full view as the view itself consists of multiple nested views. But when I replace the `ItemView` with a simple `Rectangle` with a foreground color, I observe the same scaling animation, so it's definitely not dependent on the concrete view I'm using for each item. (The main view is pretty much just the code I posted above, only that it's wrapped in a `NavigationView`.)

Comment: This needs a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should be providing enough code for us to run and reproduce the error.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez, @Yrb: Added a minimal code example where I use a `Rectangle` for the `ItemView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `didSet` won't work the way you expect, which is why we have `.onChange()`, but as you suspected, there really is a simpler way. You only want to animate appending the items to the list (which shows on screen). The simplest way to do this is to add a `@State` bool, and use that for the `.animation()` value. You then simply switch it in your button when you add to the array like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items: [Int] = []
    @State var animate = false // Variable for animation
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(), GridItem()]) {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: 50)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .transition(.scale)
                }
            }
        }
        // Use animate as a flag to allow items to be the value
        // for .animation
        .animation(.default, value: (animate ? items : []))
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button {
                    let newItem = items.last.map { $0 + 1 } ?? 0
                    items.append(newItem)
                    animate.toggle() // <- Switch it here
                } label: {
                    Text("Add Item")
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            items = [Int](0...10)
            // The DispatchQueue is necessary to delay changing
            // the flag until the initial view is loaded.
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
                animate = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

The code above has been changed to reflect the comment. This should suit your needs.

Comment: That's a nice idea that certainly works for this specific use case, but the requirement was only derived from the minimal example where I only have an add button (for simplicity) and nothing else. In my real app, I can delete items as well. So in general, I really _want_ the animation to be dependent on the `items` array as state. It makes sense to me to see this as the single source of truth and animate changes to it – I would just like to disable/defer that behavior until the initial loading is done.

Comment: Edited code per your comment.

Comment: Yup, that certainly solves the problem. I still don't find it as "elegant" as I would have wished for as it's still the same idea at its core: Introduce a second state variable as a boolean and derive the value used for animation from both of these states: the `items` array and the boolean. But I guess there is no neater way to achieve the desired behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that applying the `.animation` modifier to `LazyVGrid` instead of `ScrollView` works as you expect it to work.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var items: [Int] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(), GridItem()]) {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(height: 50)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .transition(.scale)
                    }
                }
                .animation(.default, value: items) // <- New Place
            }
            // <- Old Place
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button {
                        let newItem = items.last.map { $0 + 1 } ?? 0
                        items.append(newItem)
                    } label: {
                        Text("Add Item")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            items = [Int](0...10)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that before. It disabled the initial animation, but it comes with another major disadvantage: This way, the scroll view doesn't animate its height when items are added or deleted. For example, when I delete an item in a row of a LazyVGrid that only has one item, the scroll view's content height immediately jumps to its new reduced size while the ItemView is animated in place which causes weird animation glitches. So the ScrollView's size must be animated as well, just not in the beginning...

Comment: That would have been worth mentioning in the original question...

Answer (score 0):

To disable animating changes in SwiftUI you can encapsulate those changes in a transaction that disables animations.

Your code should look something like this:

```swift
var transaction = Transaction()
transaction.disablesAnimations = true
withTransaction(transaction) {
    // Make the changes that you don't want animated
}
```

This should work for any standard animation, including showing/dismissing sheets and full screen covers.